# Discord python, how to get all files and images uploaded to a channel?

Tags: discord.py

How can I download all the files and images posted in a channel? 
Thank you for any reply.

---

```
for channel in ctx.guild.text_channels:
    async for message in channel.history(limit=100):
        for attachment in message.attachments:
            attachment.save()
```

This the code I'm using that gives me troubles.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  As it's currently written, this question isn't likely to get any helpful answers. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips, then come back and edit your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, use `async for ... in channel.history()` [(documentation)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.history) to iterate over the messages, then use `message.attachments` [(documentation)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.attachments) to get the [attachment](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#attachment) objects. If you then want to save the attachments to your machine, use `attachment.save()` [(documentation)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Attachment.save)

Comment: Thank you for your help.